# Sharepoint 2010 people picker

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, peoplepicker

In Active directory there is just one account for user John Dlouhý, but in people picker I always get two results. Do you have any idea why this is happening ?

```
Name:                     Account name:

John Dlouhý               biz\dlouhy
John Dlouhý               biz\dlouhý
```

biz\dlouhy vs. biz\dlouhý
If I talk to Active directory directly and request these two accounts they have same SID, to there is really only one account.

Comment: can you check this user in sharepoint users profile from Central Admin?